# codenameone stores boolean values as true/false in sqlite when they should be 1/0

Tags: sqlite, boolean, codenameone

I have a class that implements PropertyBusinessObject with an entry :

```
public final Property<Boolean, TestClass> isAdmin = new Property<>("isAdmin", Boolean.class);
```

When inserting this into sqlite with (SqlMap.insert()) the values are stored as true/false and not 1 or 0

This causes issues when retrieving (SELECTing) values back. They always return as false. I believe sqlite does not support true/false literals as boolean indicators.

If I manually change the data in the db from true to 1 the aforementioned SELECT's work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this bug [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/9d831826134be24ff5e88da65d3231ccfe43a840). Didn't test it though but it should be relatively simple.

However, due to the holidays we don't plan to have a release before January 4th 2019. This might change if bugs/issues pile up though.

Comment: Thx will pick up your changes in Jan 2019 then.

Comment: Has the above fix just been released ? Am now seeing this failure :


`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
 at com.codename1.properties.SQLMap$SqlType$2.asUpdateInsertValue(SQLMap.java:69)
 at com.codename1.properties.SQLMap.insert(SQLMap.java:419)`


In your fix, "data" contains a String with the value "true". My PropertyBusinessObject has been defined as a Boolean as per my original post.

Comment: I can see a problem which I fixed here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/6e512e1839d7ff7f85c0970762596dbe9fa8790d however, it's possible that this is caused because of "true"/"false" values within the database already. The fix will be available next Friday

Comment: Hi Shai. I was getting the error with a brand new empty db too. Will wait for fix. Thank you.